# System.net.Mail authenticate with current winfows user

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, system.net.mail

How can I use the current login user credentials with System.Net.Mail?

Typically a set of credentials are created using:

```
smtp.Credentials = New NetworkCredential(username,password,domain)
```

I tried using the code below to use the current user:

```
Import System.Net.Mail
...
       Using smtp As New SmtpClient("smtp.office365.com", 587)
            smtp.EnableSsl = True ' ** ** set before Credentials
            smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = False
            smtp.Credentials = My.User.CurrentPrincipal  '<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
            Using message As New MailMessage()
                  ....
            End Using
       End Using
```

The <<<< line results in error:

```
  Unable to cast object of type 'System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal' 
  to type 'System.Net.ICredentialsByHost'.
```

Is there a way to cast the My.User/current credentials to the credential type System.Net.Mail needs?

Desktop client Win7+ x64, PC in ADS domain, user logged into Windows

Comment: I think you want to set [UseDefaultCredentials](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.usedefaultcredentials(v=vs.110).aspx) to True and not set anything to the Credentials property of the SmtpClient.

Comment: Seems reasonable - doesn't work. I'm beginning to believe System.Net.Mail for Office 365/Exchange SMTP doesn't support Active Directory, or Windows Security for that matter.

Comment: Oh, right - that's the online service. No, it won't accept your local domain user credentials. It wants a full email and password.

Comment: I was hooping the the MS Exchange server would accept domain credentials, but I guess not. Evidently System.Net.Mail is not iterated with Exchange/smtp.office365.com. I haven't seen any client side APIs for Exchange.

Comment: System.Net.Mail works with locally installed Exchange on your LAN where domain credentials are meaningful. Hosted services don't have that.

Comment: Seems reasonable - haven't seen a way to make it work however.

Comment: Do you have a local LAN-installed Exchange server? If so, the host and port need to point to that server, not the online service "smtp.office365.com"

Comment: No - cloud based Exchange as part of Office 365. SMTP is working OK - just have the annoying extra logins to send mail.